# What is the source of energy in this system? (resonance realated)

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, acoustics, resonance

This is curiosity question, sorry if description is too vague.
Suppose we have a string attached to some small frame on both sides
Then we apply a force by plucking it with a finger, lets say 5.0 N (the number is arbitrary).
The strings starts to oscillate and produces sound waves in proportion to the force we applied, little energy goes to heat, so ok, everything is clear for now.

Then we attach a wooden block to the frame and apply the same force (5.0 N) to the string.
Now wooden block starts to resonate and the sound waves now have bigger amplitude compared to first experiment.

Question: if the amount of force applied to the system is the same, why the amplitude increases? I understand that the key lies in resonance, but I suppose that resonance must take the energy from some kind of source, it can't just make the amplitude bigger using "nothing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pluck the string, you impart energy into it that's slowly radiated as sound. There are ways to radiate the energy faster, in which case the string loses energy faster. You're increasing the power and decreasing the time, so energy stays constant.

Comment: oh... seems very logical, funny I haven't thought about it. Thanks! :)